# How to get the Font name from a font file in Mac osx 10.5?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to get the font name of a font file in Mac osx 10.5. I have done this for Mac osx 10.6 using `CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL` like this.

```
        CFArrayRef fontDescription=CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL(cfUrl);
        NSDictionary *dict=[(NSArray *)fontDescription objectAtIndex:0];

        fontName=[dict objectForKey:@"NSFontNameAttribute"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Text is only available in Snow Leopard. You need to use the legacy [Apple Type Services (ATS)](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/ATS/Reference/reference.html) for Leopard and below.

Also see the [ATS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ATS_Concepts/ManagingFonts.pdf).

Comment: I saw the document but cant able to find a way to get the font name.. can you please tell which API I have to use to get the font Name ?

Comment: Use `ATSFontFamilyGetName`. You need to provide a font family reference and a string reference to store the name in.

Comment: that is the problem..I have only the font Path I have to get the font name from that path.

Comment: @Trisha: You can't go directly from a path to a font name, neither with Core Text nor with ATS. With Core Text, as your own code demonstrates, you must create a font descriptor; with ATS, you must create a font container object, then get the individual font objects from it, and then you can get the name from each font.